# Could or could have

Tags: could-modal, could

Can we use "*could*" and "*could have*" interchangeably in active voice?.. just like we can use "*could be*" and "*could have been*" interchangeably in passive voice...

I am not a native English speaker, so I get confused...

I have seen on different places that these two are also used interchangebly..
Like

> I **could do** this in 30 minutes

Similarly,

> I **could have done** this in 30 minutes"

Are these both correct?

can we use "*could*" instead of "*could have*" + past participle?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I hope you like the place and decide to visit often. You might want to [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) or to read the [Contributor's guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/91457). The guide has a lot of helpful information on how best to ask, and answer, questions here on ELL.

Answer (score 1):

*I could do this in 30 minutes* - I estimate that the task will take me half an hour.

*I could have done this in 30 minutes* - implies that the task has been done. Maybe somebody else has taken 45 minutes to do it and you think you could have done it more quickly. Maybe it took you longer, but you say you could have done it in half an hour if you had been given the right equipment.

Answer (score 0):

"Aisling could do the job easily" suggests that Aisling has the ability/capacity/willingness to do a particular job if it became necessary for it to be done. It might suggest to the listener that Aisling might be the right person to ask to do the job ... or maybe Aisling is standing there doing nothing when she could be doing this (for her) easy job.

It's a second (hypothetical but realistically possible or necessary) conditional: in the situation it is still possible and/or necessary to get the job done

On the other hand, "Aisling could have done the job easily" suggests that it's either no longer necessary or too late to do the job, but that Aisling would have had the ability/capacity/willingness to do it if it were still an option or requirement. In some circumstances it (for example) might be a criticism of Aisling for not having done it, in others it might be just another way of telling the listener "you could have asked Aisling" (maybe the listener did it themselves rather laboriously when it would have been much easier just to ask Aisling.

It's a third (hypothetical and not - no longer - realistically possible or necessary) conditional: in the situation it is no longer possible and/or necessary to get the job done.

[https://www.engvid.com/second-third-conditionals/#:~:text=For%20example%3A%20%22If%20you%20heat,would%20have%20become%20an%20engineer.%22](https://www.engvid.com/second-third-conditionals/#:%7E:text=For%20example%3A%20%22If%20you%20heat,would%20have%20become%20an%20engineer.%22)